# Laravel docker deploy

Tags: laravel, docker

I have a Laravel project where we integrate create container with docker.
I'm using the SSH plugin for laravel to SSH.

I'm trying to execute the follow code:

```
SSH::into('production')->run([
                'docker run --expose '.$port.' --expose '.$rpcport.' --name '.$nodeName.' -i cimage:latest bash',
                'docker start '.$nodeName,
                'docker exec -i -t '.$nodeName.' mkdir /usr/local/bin/test',
            ]);
```

The node create perfect and start good.

Problem is the next commands not executing or something in the command is not good.

Can someone help me to get this solve?

Comment: You could try adding `--detach` option to run the command in background, otherwise the command could be displaying information and would not allow the following command to be run

Comment: I think docker start is not needed because after run command container keeps running and last command needs a bash -c "mkdir..."

Answer (score 0):

It works with execute the commands separate like:

```
SSH::into('production')->run([
                'docker run --expose '.$port.' --expose '.$rpcport.' --name '.$nodeName.' -i cimage:latest bash',
            ]);

SSH::into('production')->run([
                'docker exec -i -t '.$nodeName.' mkdir /usr/local/bin/test',
            ]);
```